# replace only some part of current page on click of link Using javascript

Tags: javascript, dynamic-content

Current scenario

[image]

Hi i want to load page onclick of link that will replace only some part of page.I don't want to load new page or tab.The part to replace should be dynamic and rest should be static.Any suggestion.I tried window.location and other options but didn't meet requirement.

Comment: Do you have any server-side component? Or purely client-side?

Comment: if you are getting the "parts" from a server, you'll need to employ some sort of AJAX to meet your requirements

Comment: Hi I have added image where you can see multi links on right side.

Comment: I have added image where middle stream needs to replace after clicking link on right side

Answer (score 0):

One way is to load the "dynamic part" of the page in an iframe inside the "static part" of the page.

Another option is for you to figure out how to update the DOM content of a HTML element (for example more commonly a div) using JavaScript and how/where to load the DOM content from.